# Prae- & Ante- (before)

Tags: meaning, word-comparison, prefix

The prefixes *prae-* and *ante-* both have the same meaning of 'before' in place or time. Why is the existence of both words necessary?

Answer (score 10):

There are differences between the two words.
Lewis and Short give a detailed account of both [*prae*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D82%3Aentry%3Dprae) and [*ante*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D82%3Aentry%3Dprae).
There are situations where they are interchangeable, but they are not synonymous everywhere.

For details, see the two dictionary entries.
Here are some points to highlight the difference:

- Both *ante* and *prae* mean "before" in a spatial sense, but *ante* is used for objects at rest and *prae* for objects in motion.
- *Prae* has the sense "because", *ante* does not.
- When it comes to time, *ante* seems to be far more common for "before". (I get the impression that *prae* isn't possible at all, apart from giving that sense in compounds.)

When you look at a dictionary that gives a couple of English words for a Latin word as translation options, they can look identical.
When you look at a dictionary that gives detailed explanations, much more nuance emerges.

So, the two prepositions are different.
Used as prefixes they are much closer to each other than as prepositions.
But even if it was not necessary to have both, they can still coexist; synonyms are not that rare.
The meanings of the two words have certainly evolved through time, and that might explain how we ended up having these two very similar prepositions.
Perhaps *ante* was more "against" and *prae* more "before".
I would say that it is not necessary to have both *ante* and *prae*, but we still do, and it does allow expressing some things more accurately.

Comment: So could you use *ante* for a single point in time, and *præ* for a period (multiple points) in time – since motion technically is a change/difference/comparison between two or more points? E.g. *pre-history* (history is a progression) is made up of *anterior moments* (single points fixed in time).

Comment: @Matt Welcome to the site! I don't think there's a distinction like that, but I've been wrong before. Both *prior* and *anterior* exist, but I haven't studied whether they are related like *prae* and *ante* are. If there are two similar words like *ante* and *prae*, there rarely is a clear division of labor between them. If you want more details, please [ask a new question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).